# Код не выдает ошибки, но и графика нет

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = [[0] * 2 for i in range(2)]
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print('введите выигрыш первого игрока при ', i+1, 'ой стратегии первого игрока и ' , j+1, 'ой стратегии второго игрока ')
        m[i][j]=int(input())
M = [[0] * 2 for i in range(2)]
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print('введите выигрыш второго игрока при ', i+1, 'ой стратегии первого игрока и ' , j+1, 'ой стратегии второго игрока ')
        M[i][j]=int(input())
a=m[0][0]-m[0][1]-m[1][0]+m[1][1]
b=m[0][1]-m[1][1]
c=m[1][0]-m[1][1]
d=m[1][1]
A=M[0][0]-M[0][1]-M[1][0]+M[1][1]
B=M[0][1]-M[1][1]
C=M[1][0]-M[1][1]
D=M[1][1]
print('введите шаг вероятности')
k=float(input())
n=int(((1+k)/k)+1)
y=0
x=0
strx=[d]*1
stry=[D]*1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        S2=(x*y*A)+(x*B)+(y*C)+D
        S1=(x*y*a)+(x*b)+(y*c)+d
        strx.append(S1)
        stry.append(S2)
        y=y+k
    y=0
    x=x+k
plt.scatter(strx,stry)
x=strx[0]
k=0 
for i in range(1,n**2+1):
    if strx[i]<x:
        x=strx[i]
        y=stry[i]
        k=int(i)
    else:
        if strx[i]==x:
            if stry[i]<stry[k]:
                x=strx[i]
                y=stry[i]
                k=int(i)
r=int(k) 
sx=[x]*1
sy=[y]*1
sk=[k]*1
csn=-1 
l=0 
for i in range(1,n**2+1): 
    Af=(strx[i]-sx[0]) 
    Bf=(stry[i]-sy[0]) 
    Cf=math.sqrt(Af**2+Bf**2) 
    if i!=k and Cf!=0:
        cs=Bf/Cf 
        if csn<cs: 
            csn=cs
            l=int(i)
            x=strx[i]
            y=stry[i]
        else:
            if csn==cs:
                if strx[i]>x:
                    x=strx[i]
                    y=stry[i]
                    l=int(i)
k=int(l) 
sx.append(x)
sy.append(y)
sk.append(k)
csn=1 
N=1   
while k!=r: 
    for i in range(1,n**2+1): 
        v=1
        for j in range(1,N+1):
            if i==sk[j]:
                v=0 
        if v==1:
            Af=math.sqrt((strx[i]-sx[N])**2+(stry[i]-sy[N])**2) 
            Bf=math.sqrt((sx[N]-sx[N-1])**2+(sy[N]-sy[N-1])**2) 
            Cf=math.sqrt((strx[i]-sx[N-1])**2+(stry[i]-sy[N-1])**2) 
            if (Af*Bf)!=0:
                cs=(Af**2+Bf**2-Cf**2)/(2*Af*Bf) 
                if cs<csn: 
                    csn=cs
                    l=int(i)
                    x=strx[i]
                    y=stry[i]
                    Cf1=Cf
                else:
                    if csn==cs: 
                        if Cf>Cf1:
                            x=strx[i]
                            y=stry[i]
                            l=int(i)
                            Cf1=Cf
    k=int(l)
    sx.append(x) 
    sy.append(y)
    sk.append(k)
    N=N+1 
    csn=1
plt.plot(sx,sy, 'r') 
plt.plot()
```

Comment: Мне кажется, код в вопросе нужно отформатировать. Мне кажется тут отступов не хватает....

Answer (score 0):

В самый конец добавьте строчку

```
plt.show()
```